# How do I deal with unneeded inherited members?

Tags: c#, inheritance, encapsulation

Consider the following UML diagram:

[image]

In a nutshell:

- `ChildClass1` and `ChildClass2` use all of the members of `ParentClass`.
- `ChildClass3`only uses `Member1` and `Member2` and the value of `Member5` is a constant value. (0)

What would be the best way to implement this behaviour?

At the moment, I've inherited the class as normal and overridden `Member3` and `Member4` to throw `NotSupportedException` and made `Member5` read-only and return `0` all the time.

I'm not convinced this is the best idea as `Member3` and `Member4` are irrelevant to `ChildClass3`.

Other things I've considered:

- Instead of inheriting. Creating a `ParentClass` inside `ChildClass3` and then exposing only the properties I need.
- Using interfaces, but this got too messy, too quickly.
- Restructuring the hierarchy, but I didn't really look at this in too much detail.

Is there any other options?

**For context:**
I tried to keep this simple to avoid walls of code, but this appears to have lead to confusion. Oops =/

ParentClass in this case is Person, with the following fields:

- Forename : string
- Surname : string
- Gender: string
- DateOfBirth : Nullable<DateTime>
- Location: int

Now in most cases, the child classes (Employee, Manager, etc.) use all of these fields. However one class (Visitor), I only need to know a name, I don't care about their age or location. Location in this case is set to 0. I know it's a magic number, but it's important to the system.

I can understand how this violates LSP, but at the same time, I don't really think having interfaces to split a name and other personal information makes a lot of sense. Naming this would give me a headache too.

In the other classes, there's interfaces everywhere; IMedicalData, IContactInformation, etc.

I only chose inheritance in this case since a visitor is technically a type of person.

Comment: You haven't told us anything about the behavior these classes implement, what these five members are, or why two of them are irrelevant to this new derived class you're contemplating. I don't think we can give you meaningful advice without that information. When the question is phrased this abstractly the only correct answer is "it depends".

Comment: "Restructuring the hierarchy, but I didn't really look at this in too much detail." - I think this is the key statement here. I think this is the way to go, most probably

Comment: I've added a bit more context to the question, hopefully this clears up any ambiguity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually you should do it this way:

[image: uml]

This is the most canonical way of solving your problem. In general you ***add*** behaviors and states when subclassing

Answer (score 4):

> At the moment, I've inherited the class as normal and overridden `Member3` and `Member4` to throw `NotSupportedException` and made `Member5` read-only and return `0` all the time.
>
> I'm not convinced this is the best idea as Member3 and Member4 are irrelevant to ChildClass3.

It isn't the best idea: this is a classic example of violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

The simple answer to how best to implement it is "don't use inheritance; use interfaces & composition as required".

The more detailed answer has to make some guesses about what `Member[1-5]` are, but something like:

```
public interface IMember12And5
{
    Member1;
    Member2;
    Member5;
}

public interface IAllMembers : IMember12And5
{
    Member3;
    Member4;
}

public class ChildClass1 : IAllMembers  { ... }

public class ChildClass2 : IAllMembers  { ... }

public class ChildClass3 : IMember12And5 { ... }
```

might work. Alternatively, compose `ChildClass[1-2]` from `Member12And5` and `Member3And4` and have `ChildClass3` composed only of `Member12And5`.

Without more detail of what the members really are, a better answer cannot be offered.

Comment: Was away from the desk. I'll amend the question now.